# Como reduzir essa função PHP / MYSQL adicionando dados em várias colunas?

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, Tenho uma variável privada **$group_permissions** que armazena todas colunas de de permissões, elas colunas tem o valor **false** ou **true**, para dizer se o usuário tem permissão para executar algum no painel.

O usuário marca vários checkbox, e os enviam por uma variável array chamada **$p_permissions** , após ela chegar na função, através de um in_array é verificado se o valor veio, caso venha é transformando a variavéll com nome da coluna = true.

Gostaria de reduzir essa função, mas como posso fazer?

```
public function add($id_subscribers, $p_name, $p_description, $p_permissions = ''){

// VARIAVEIS ACCOUNTS, PRODUCTS, SALES, PURCHASES, FINANCIAL, SETTINGS
$accounts_view = 'false'; $accounts_add = 'false'; $accounts_edit = 'false'; $accounts_delete = 'false';
$products_view = 'false'; $products_add = 'false'; $products_edit = 'false'; $products_delete = 'false';
$sales_view = 'false'; $sales_add = 'false'; $sales_edit = 'false'; $sales_delete = 'false';
$purchases_view = 'false'; $purchases_add = 'false'; $purchases_edit = 'false'; $purchases_delete = 'false';
$financial_view = 'false'; $financial_add = 'false'; $financial_edit = 'false'; $financial_delete = 'false';
$settings_view = 'false'; $settings_add = 'false'; $settings_edit = 'false'; $settings_delete = 'false';

// CASO ESTEJA NA ARRAY - Accounts
if(in_array("accounts_view", $p_permissions)){$accounts_view = 'true';}
if(in_array("accounts_add", $p_permissions)){$accounts_add = 'true';}
if(in_array("accounts_edit", $p_permissions)){$accounts_edit = 'true';}
if(in_array("accounts_delete", $p_permissions)){$accounts_delete = 'true';}
// CASO ESTEJA NA ARRAY - Products
if(in_array("products_view", $p_permissions)){$products_view = 'true';}
if(in_array("products_add", $p_permissions)){$products_add = 'true';}
if(in_array("products_edit", $p_permissions)){$products_edit = 'true';}
if(in_array("products_delete", $p_permissions)){$products_delete = 'true';}
// CASO ESTEJA NA ARRAY - Sales
if(in_array("sales_view", $p_permissions)){$sales_view = 'true';}
if(in_array("sales_add", $p_permissions)){$sales_add = 'true';}
if(in_array("sales_edit", $p_permissions)){$sales_edit = 'true';}
if(in_array("sales_delete", $p_permissions)){$sales_delete = 'true';}
// CASO ESTEJA NA ARRAY - Purchases
if(in_array("purchases_view", $p_permissions)){$purchases_view = 'true';}
if(in_array("purchases_add", $p_permissions)){$purchases_add = 'true';}
if(in_array("purchases_edit", $p_permissions)){$purchases_edit = 'true';}
if(in_array("purchases_delete", $p_permissions)){$purchases_delete = 'true';}
// CASO ESTEJA NA ARRAY - Financial
if(in_array("financial_view", $p_permissions)){$financial_view = 'true';}
if(in_array("financial_add", $p_permissions)){$financial_add = 'true';}
if(in_array("financial_edit", $p_permissions)){$financial_edit = 'true';}
if(in_array("financial_delete", $p_permissions)){$financial_delete = 'true';}
// CASO ESTEJA NA ARRAY - Settings
if(in_array("settings_view", $p_permissions)){$settings_view = 'true';}
if(in_array("settings_add", $p_permissions)){$settings_add = 'true';}
if(in_array("settings_edit", $p_permissions)){$settings_edit = 'true';}
if(in_array("settings_delete", $p_permissions)){$settings_delete = 'true';}

// INSERT no banco de dados
$sql = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO cms_accounts_acess (id_subscribers, name, description, accounts_view, accounts_add, accounts_edit, accounts_delete, products_view, products_add, products_edit, products_delete, sales_view, sales_add, sales_edit, sales_delete, purchases_view, purchases_add, purchases_edit, purchases_delete, financial_view, financial_add, financial_edit, financial_delete, settings_view, settings_add, settings_edit, settings_delete) VALUES (:id_subscribers, :p_name, :p_description, :accounts_view, :accounts_add, :accounts_edit, :accounts_delete, :products_view, :products_add, :products_edit, :products_delete, :sales_view, :sales_add, :sales_edit, :sales_delete, :purchases_view, :purchases_add, :purchases_edit, :purchases_delete, :financial_view, :financial_add, :financial_edit, :financial_delete, :settings_view, :settings_add, :settings_edit, :settings_delete)");

// INSERT no banco de dados
/*$sql = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO cms_accounts_acess SET id_subscribers = :id_subscribers, name = :name, description = :description, accounts_view = :accounts_view, accounts_add = :accounts_add, accounts_edit = :accounts_edit, accounts_delete = :accounts_delete, products_view = :products_view, products_add = :products_add, products_edit = :products_edit, products_delete = :products_delete, sales_view = :sales_view, sales_add = :sales_add, sales_edit = :sales_edit, sales_delete = :sales_delete, purchases_view = :purchases_view, purchases_add = :purchases_add, purchases_edit = :purchases_edit, purchases_delete = :purchases_delete, financial_view = :financial_view, financial_add = :financial_add, financial_edit = :financial_edit, financial_delete = :financial_delete, settings_view = :settings_view, settings_add = :settings_add, settings_edit = :settings_edit, settings_delete = :settings_delete");*/





$sql->bindValue(":id_subscribers", $id_subscribers);
$sql->bindValue(":p_name", $p_name);
$sql->bindValue(":p_description", $p_description);
$sql->bindValue(":accounts_view", $accounts_view);
$sql->bindValue(":accounts_add", $accounts_add);
$sql->bindValue(":accounts_edit", $accounts_edit);
$sql->bindValue(":accounts_delete", $accounts_delete);
$sql->bindValue(":products_view", $products_view);
$sql->bindValue(":products_add", $products_add);
$sql->bindValue(":products_edit", $products_edit);
$sql->bindValue(":products_delete", $products_delete);
$sql->bindValue(":sales_view", $sales_view);
$sql->bindValue(":sales_add", $sales_add);
$sql->bindValue(":sales_edit", $sales_edit);
$sql->bindValue(":sales_delete", $sales_delete);
$sql->bindValue(":purchases_view", $purchases_view);
$sql->bindValue(":purchases_add", $purchases_add);
$sql->bindValue(":purchases_edit", $purchases_edit);
$sql->bindValue(":purchases_delete", $purchases_delete);
$sql->bindValue(":financial_view", $financial_view);
$sql->bindValue(":financial_add", $financial_add);
$sql->bindValue(":financial_edit", $financial_edit);
$sql->bindValue(":financial_delete", $financial_delete);
$sql->bindValue(":settings_view", $settings_view);
$sql->bindValue(":settings_add", $settings_add);
$sql->bindValue(":settings_edit", $settings_edit);
$sql->bindValue(":settings_delete", $settings_delete);
$sql->execute();    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrays

```
$permissions = ['accounts', 'products', 'sales', 'purchases', 'financial', 'settings'];
$modifiers = ['view', 'add', 'edit', 'delete'];

foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
    foreach ($modifiers as $modifier) { 
        $set_permissions[$permission.'_'.$modifier] = in_array($permission.'_'.$modifier, $p_permissions) ? 'true' : 'false';
    }
}

$indexes = array_keys($set_permissions);

$sql = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO cms_accounts_acess (id_subscribers, name, description, '.implode(', ', $indexes).') VALUES (:id_subscribers, :p_name, :p_description, :'.implode(', :', $indexes).')');
$sql->bindValue(':id_subscribers', $id_subscribers);
$sql->bindValue(':p_name', $p_name);
$sql->bindValue(':p_description', $p_description);

foreach ($set_permissions as $key => $value) {
    $sql->bindValue(':'.$key, $value);
}

$sql->execute();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! estou iniciando no ramo e me ajudou muito!

Comment: No caso do UPDATE, tentei utllizar um imploder para atualizar mas gera erro print_r(implode('= :'.$indexes.', ', $indexes));
 exit;